# Inner divs padding affects outer div positioning. (margin collapsing?)

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<p>messy</p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="one wrapper">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="two wrapper">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="three wrapper">
            <div class="foo">3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<p>good</p>

<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="one wrapper">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="two wrapper">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="three wrapper">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
.row {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:blue;
    width:100%;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    padding:0;
    display: block;
    height:42px;
    background-color:red;
}
.one {
    width:100px;
}
.two {
    width:40px;
}
.three {
    width:100px;
}
.foo {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

You can see the fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/wf3g6/).

Why is `three` messing up the layout in case a child has a padding? I've read various articles about [**margin collapsing**](http://complexspiral.com/publications/uncollapsing-margins/) in the past, but I could'nt fix this layout using one of the techniques.

Comment: I hate tables. It seem that divs with `display: table` and `display: table-cell` use to inherit some of their mysterious habits.

Comment: I toyed with it a while and couldn't come up with any good solution I liked.  What is the exact appearance/layout you're looking for?  There is probably a way to do it without using display:table… or maybe with.  Do you just want the second "good" display, but with the number 3 to have 10px padding?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to avoid table and table-cell. The cell divs have to auto align on the row with 100% width. I'm afraid the only solution for the desired beheaviour of the cells is to use https://github.com/codler/Grid-Layout-Polyfill. In an ideal CSS world, I want the wrapper divs to have no effect on the outer row, so that I can use absolute positioning, padding and vertical aligning inside of it =/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple just add `vertical-align: middle;` in `.cell` Class.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wf3g6/2/)**